# Out of memory: kill process Apache

Tags: ubuntu, unix, memory

I got the following error message in Unix log: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/outOfMemory.png

I'm just running a drupal website. What does that mean ? Is related to the RAM of my unix system ?

Or is some other functionality ?

thanks

Comment: Your picture link has gone stale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When finished memory, system kill apache process.

1 Reduced MaxSpareServers,MaxClients

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html

example:

```
StartServers       1
MinSpareServers    1
MaxSpareServers    5
MaxClients        10
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
```

2 Add memory and then use optimal config:

```
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
ServerLimit 50
StartServers 15
MinSpareServers 15
MaxSpareServers 20
MaxClients 50
MaxRequestsPerChild 500
```

Comment: what memory are we talking about ? RAM memory of my server ? Or is just an Apache setting ?

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely a RAM problem, you might run out of memory and your system invoke the OOM-killer and start killing processes to free up memory, I guess this is a system with little RAM and apache is eating that RAM.

More information about your server, confiruation of apache and your site habits would be useful in this case as it could shed some light as to whether you need more RAM or just better configure your apache.

Hope that helped